# Returned One M8 to stock but can't install OTAs

Tags: unrooting, stock-rom

My UK EE One M8 was unlocked, rooted and running a custom ROM.  The CID is ORANG001.

I wanted to return it to stock so installed stock recovery and a stock ORANG001 nandroid, relocked the bootloader and returned to S-ON.

[image]

It all looks OK but when I start receivng the OTAs, I get this error.

`We have determined that your phone may be running a modified version of it's system software.`

What have I missed?

Comment: Are you sure there's been no modifications to the system partition? You should double check.

Comment: @keepcalm Sorry, that's a bit above my knowledge level.  How can I check?  What do I do if it is modified?  Cheers

Comment: Are you sure the nandroid you restored is completely stock (no leftover root or anything)? It's been a while since I used an HTC so I might be a bit rusty, but have you tried using a different Nandroid (maybe one of the ones [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2701376)), or manually applying one of the OTAs in that thread?